# Show that a CW-complex is contractible without Whitehead theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

I was trying to solve the following problem:

Let $X$ a CW- complex such that the inclusion $X_{n-1} \hookrightarrow X_n $ are null-homotopic, then $X$ is contractible.

I already know that Whitehead theorem solve it, but I was searching a proof that does not use the theorem.

Comment: Isn't that false? Take $X=S^1$ with $X_0$ being a point. So there's only one inclusion which is null-homotopic because it's constant.

Comment: I think you must implicitly suppose that $X_n$ in cofinally non empty to make the question makes sense.

Comment: In the case of $S^1$, I think $X_n = S^1$ for $n\ge 1$ and $S^1\to S^1$ is not null-homotopic.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was not clear.In the case of $S^1$  the n skeleton are all $S^1$ for all $n\ge1$

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot that the $n$-skeleton is defined as the union of cells of dimension **at most** $n$.

Comment: You probably want to use the homotopy extension property to build up a contraction skeleton by skeleton. Notice that the inclusions $X_n \to X$ are all null-homotopic as well.

Comment: My idea was that if we suppose that each inclusion is homotopic to constant $x_0$ for some fixed $x_0$. Then for each $n$ , since $(X,X_n)$ has HEP we can extend the homotopy  $f_t^n:X_n  \rightarrow X$  from the inclusion to $x_0$  to a map $g_t^n X\rightarrow X$  and then define $$H_t X\rightarrow X$$ such that for each $t \in [1-2^{-n}, 1-2^{n+1}]$ $$H_t=g_{2^{n+1}t -2^{n+1} +2}\circ g_1^n \circ \dots \circ g_1^1$$ and $$H_1=x_0$$, this is continuous since the restriction on each $X_n$ it is. Note that for each point in $X$ only finitely many $g_t^n$ move that point.