# Contractibility of CW complex without Whitehead

Tags: homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, higher-homotopy-groups

Suppose I have a CW complex $X$ with skeleta $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ such that $\pi_k(X)=0$ for all $k\ge 0$. I want to conclude that $X$ is contractible without invoking Whitehead's theorem.

It would be enough to see that the identity $X$ is nullhomotopic. My strategy would be the following:

1. Show that all inclusions $i_n:X_n\hookrightarrow X$ are null-homotopic,
2. Conclude somehow that the limit $\varinjlim\, (i_n)=\mathrm{id}$ is null-homotopic.

Comment: What is your question: Whether your strategy is adequate or do you want to see a proof?

Comment: I want to have a proof but I thought it is a good idea to tell you what I have so far. If there's a proof using another approach, I would be happy, too.

Comment: The same as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2512136